# I am unable to activate my openvpn service

Tags: openvpn

My openvpn service is stuck at activating.What should I do?

`openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; indirect; vendor preset
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-12-03 11
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
  Process: 27945 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/
 Main PID: 27945 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Pre-connection initialization successful"`

Comment: Read the log files and include anything out of the ordinary in the question.